# Visual Studio 2019 dark theme: How to copy and paste code to MS Word with default syntax highlighting?

Tags: visual-studio

I want to copy the code portion from Visual Studio 2019 Community, with Dark Theme set, and paste it to MS Word with preserving the copied text styles as it was done in Visual Studio 2017 - with the default code styling.

Visual Studio 2017 with Dark Theme - copy result (that is what I want):
[image]

Visual Studio 2019 with Dark Theme - copy result (unwanted):
[image]

How to preserve that behaviour in VS 2019?

I tested [Copy As Html](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.CopyAsHtml) extension but it didn't seem to solve the issue (or I am missing something).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Install Productivity Power Tools From Extensions.
2. Restart Visual Studio.
3. Go to Tools -> Options -> Protectivity Power Tools -> HTML Copy and:-

a. Change BeforeCodeSnippet to:-

`<style type='text/css'> .user{color:#006600 !important} .identifier{color: black !important;} .keyword{color: blue !important;} .literal{color: black !important;} .operator{color: black !important;} .string{color: #A31515 !important;} .number{color: black !important;} .Types{color: #2B91AF !important;} .Class{color: #2B91AF !important;} .delegate{color: #2B91AF !important;} .Interface{color: #79B351 !important;} .Interface.name{color: #79B351 !important;} .enum{color: #79B351 !important;} .enum.name{color: #79B351 !important;} .enum.member.name{color: black !important;} .comment{color: #008000 !important;} </style> <pre>`

b. Change EmitSpanClass to **true**.

c. Check if EmitSpanStyle is true.

4. Restart Visual Studio.

Comment: Nice. Where did you get it from? :)

Comment: I got the same problem and a non-answered Question
so I Search until I got a solution from a lot of websites.
and I summary it here.

Comment: I added extra code to make it more Clear when I copy-paste

Comment: Not working on Visual Studio 2022. See: https://github.com/microsoft/VS-PPT/issues/252